# jQuery dynamic selection stops working after initial trigger

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a page with several lightboxes. The button for the lightbox is this:

```
<button class="lightbox" data-lb="result-slide1">See More Results</button>
```

The lightbox is triggered like this:

```
var lightboxButtons = $('.lightbox');

lightboxButtons.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var button = $(this);
    var lightboxData = button.attr("data-lb");
    overlay.fadeIn();
    lightboxDisplay(lightboxData);
});
```

And the lightbox is displayed like this:

```
function lightboxDisplay(content) {
    var lightboxHTML = $('#' + content);
    lightboxContent.html(lightboxHTML);
    lightboxContainer.fadeIn();
};
```

So basically the script gets the element with the `id` that matches the button's `data-lb` attribute, and puts that element's html into the lightbox.

The problem is that this stops working if these steps happen:

1. Lightbox button A is triggered
2. Lightbox button B is triggered
3. Lightbox button A is triggered again

When this happens, the lightbox displays, but doesn't have any content in it. When I `console.log(lightboxHTML)` it shows an empty object if those steps are followed, so the problem has something to do with that variable somehow. Thanks for looking.

EDIT: Here is the function that runs when a close button is clicked:

```
function lightboxReset() {
    overlay.fadeOut();
    lightboxContainer.fadeOut();
};
```

EDIT2: Here is some HTML of what might go into the lightbox from the jQuery selection:

```
<article class="slide-content results-lb-container" id="result-slide1">
    <img src="img/profile-placeholder.png" alt="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent at eleifend orci. Aliquam ac bibendum erat. Sed dapibus placerat feugiat. Nam et risus a purus scelerisque dignissim at ac purus. Donec dapibus nulla et lectus fringilla elementum. Vivamus orci ipsum, tincidunt id nisl posuere, rutrum imperdiet nibh. Fusce vitae dignissim libero. Nulla vel sapien urna. Fusce et mauris et neque imperdiet suscipit. In pretium elit felis, in consequat nulla ornare et. Etiam finibus nibh lorem, vitae placerat magna commodo ut.</p>
</article>
```

Comment: What does `console.log(content)` show?

Comment: It shows whatever the `data-lb` attribute string was of the button clicked.

Comment: What happens when you close the lightbox? My guess is that the problem is there: In your example you actually don't add HTML but a jQuery object to your lightbox. If you somehow edit that on closing the lightbox (e.g. delete it or empty it), that could be the reason.

Comment: I will add the script to my question that happens on close, 1 sec.

Comment: Can you make an executable stack snippet that demonstrates the problem? It's hard to see the whole context from the little bit you've shown.

Comment: If `content` is correct but `lightboxHTML` is empty, the `content` ID must not refer to an existing element.

Comment: Where is `lightboxContainer` defined ?

Comment: @Barmar there is an existing element because the button always works the first time it is triggered. It only fails if a different lightbox is triggered, and then the first one is triggered again.

Comment: Which suggests that something is removing the element before you trigger it again.

Comment: Can you create a stacksnippets https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ to demonstrate ?

Comment: @Barmar ah I hadn't thought of that, how would I be able to tell if that's happening? When I look at the page source, the corresponding element is always in there whether or not the error occurs.

Comment: replace this line in your function see if that works
       `lightboxContent.html(lightboxHTML.html());`

Comment: As I already said: I also agree with @Barmar that something is removing your element and I'm fairly certain that *something* is you. Just a wild guess, but try changing the first line of `lightboxDisplay` to `var lightboxHTML = $('#' + content).html();`

Comment: @mmgross that solves the problem, but unfortunately kills all of the styling I need to apply to the lightbox content.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? It's really difficult to provide you with a fully working solution without seeing the whole picture.

Comment: @JesseDillman That's just another reason why we need to see more of the code. There's lots going on here that you haven't shown.

Comment: @mmgross Two of us have already asked him to supply a stack snippet.

Comment: I can setup a fiddle, but it will take awhile before I can get to that atm, sorry.

Comment: So what do you get when you log `lightboxHTML.html()`? Maybe your lightboxHTML is missing the id and class contributing to the styling

Comment: @Adjit Ahhhhh, I see. It's missing the container, and a lot of my styling was nested. THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
function lightboxDisplay(content) {
    var lightboxHTML = $('#' + content);
    lightboxContent.html(lightboxHTML.html());
    lightboxContainer.fadeIn();
};
```

Comment: Why would that make a difference? If `lightboxHTML` is an empty jQuery collection, why would calling `.html()` on it return anything useful?

Comment: And if this were the problem, why would it work the first time, but not the second time?

Comment: This actually does solve the issue. It's the same solution that @mmgross proposed too. As I replied to him, it fixes the problem, but unfortunately kills all of the styling I need from the HTML in the lightbox.

Comment: @Barmar that solves the problem because OP is somehow deleting the element while it is inside the lightbox. If only the HTML is added and not the element itself it won't be deleted. But I think Matt.k should change gis answer to explain it better.

Comment: @JesseDillman how are you setting the styling for the HTML of `lightboxHTML`?

Comment: The documentation of `.html()` doesn't say what it does when the argument is an object rather than a string. I assumed it simply copied the object's HTML, but it sounds like it's more like `lightboxContent.empty(); lightboxContent.append(lightboxHTML)`, which moves the `lightboxHTML` element.

Comment: @Adjit not sure how specific you'd want me to get with that. I'm just using classes and an external CSS file for those styles.

Comment: @mmgross I think it's being deleted because the .html() method is overwriting the contents of the lightbox with a new jQuery object whenever a new button is clicked. Is there a different way of doing this that doesn't overwrite the initial object?

Comment: @JesseDillman well do you want to append the content instead of replacing it? that might be better suited for your needs. Try `.append()`

Comment: @Adjit Well I would still need to somehow remove or hide the lightbox content appended from previous triggers, and I'm not sure how that would be different from just using `.html()` to overwrite the content.

Comment: @JesseDillman Could you maybe show us what the HTML of your `lightbox` looks like? also is your `lightboxHTML` strictly HTML or would you just need to grab the text from it?

Comment: @Adjit Just edited the question with the HTML of a lightbox. It will need to be HTML.

Comment: This solved the issue, and with the help of @Adjit I got the styling working again. Accepted.